# How to change menu li class when div changes

Tags: javascript, menu

I'm working on a one-page site that has several "articles". Each div has class "article" and id "first", "second", "third", etc. I have a standard menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="n1"><a href="#first"></a></li> 
  <li id="n2"><a href="#second"></a></li>
  <li id="n3"><a href="#third"></a></li>
  //...etc             
</ul>
```

What I need to do is assign the class "active" to the li tag w/id n1 when the current article has id "first" (and unassign active class from all other li tags); assign active class to li tag w/id n2 when current article has id "second"; etc.

I would appreciate any help... I'm really stuck on this one. TIA for your help.

P.S. I'm using the following code to, in essence, assign an active class to the currently viewed article:

```
$('#first, #second, #third, ...).bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        if (visible == true) {
        $(this).addClass("inview");     
        } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inview");
        }   
});
```

Comment: is the class `active` for the sake of some CSS?

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to do it. This is one, which may give you ideas:

```
var navrefs= document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0, len = navrefs.length;i<len;i++){
  if (location.hash == navrefs[i].href){
     navrefs[i].parentNode.className = 'active'; 
  } else {
     navrefs[i].parentNode.className = ''; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Here's an example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPTj/)

The following assumes you have the class `current` on your currently active article page:

```
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('article'),
    al = articles.length,
    which, i;

for (i = 0; i < al; i++) {
    if (/current/.test(articles[i].className)) {
        which = articles[i].id;
    }
}

var atags = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    al2 = atags.length;

for (i = 0; i < al2; i++) {
    if (atags[i].href.search(which) > -1) {
        atags[i].parentNode.className = 'active';
    } else {
        atags[i].parentNode.className = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's to achieve a CSS effect, why not just right CSS like this:

```
.first #n1,
.second #n2,
.third #n3,
...etc 
 {
   CSS for active article
}
```

and then just make the JS in charge of setting the appropriate class on the wrapper/body, e.g.

```
<li id="n1"><a href="#first" onclick="setC('first')"></a></li>
etc.
...
function setC(str){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').className=str;
}
```

This would would reduce the demand on the JS engine

Comment: Thanks. This was my original thought about how to handle this; however, the user can navigate to the different "articles" simply by scrolling down the page, and not just by clicking on a menu link.

Comment: @javascript huh, so you are determining current article by scroll position?